# swapping textarea with text-box and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following jQuery code is not working. Please check the demo the blur event is causing the problem

```
//code to change textbox
$('.SpeakMindInputArea').live("click",function(){
    $(this).hide().next().show(5).focus();
    $(this).next().find('textarea').first().focus();

});
$('.SpeakMindField').live("blur",function(){
    $(this).find('.SpeakMindInputArea').first().show().next().hide();        
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CwZKq/

I want on click of textbox it to change to textarea and on blur to revet back. But if I try to submit the form it needs to stay as it is.

Comment: Reposting question is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for somethign like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CwZKq/11/

```
//code to change textbox
$('.SpeakMindInputArea input').live("focus",function(){
    $(this).parent().hide().next().show().find('textarea').focus();
});

$('.SpeakMindTextArea textarea').live("blur",function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show();
});
```

**Update:** now it handles submits: http://jsfiddle.net/CwZKq/13/

```
//code to change textbox
$('.SpeakMindInputArea input').live("focus",function(){
    $('.SpeakMindTextArea textarea:visible').parent().hide().prev().show();        
    $(this).parent().hide().next().show().find('textarea').focus();
});
```

Comment: thanks but in this case even if i try to submit the form blur event gets fired

Comment: Check the second smaple I've added to answer.

Comment: I've removed it because if you will try to click on submit button blur even will fire and textarea will be chaned back to textbox

Comment: yes i saw that and i want to change it back if no content exist

Comment: So, I understand you correct that first sample was OK for you. The only thing is that you don't neeed to revert back to text box in case if something exists in textarea? Am I right?

Comment: If you type something in one of the textareas and then go on to another field, the first textarea becomes an input again

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$('.SpeakMindInputArea').live("focus",function(){
        $('.SpeakMindTextArea').not(this).hide().prev().show();
        $(this).hide().next().show().find('textarea').focus();
    });
```

In this scenario, if a textarea is displayed it will only be hidden if another text box is clicked on.